# Span doesn't loads animation

Tags: html, css

Here's the thing: Im trying to add a simple animation to a letter encapsulated in a span tag, it has one class assigned (the animation per se), but it doesn't shows up.

I might be missing a fundamental thing, but I would like you to check it out:

```css
.title-pos{
   top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 500px;
    top:0
}

.title-style{
    font-size:35px;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif;
}

.letter-rotated{
    font-size:70px;
    font-weight:600;
  transition: 1.5s;
}

.letter-rotated{
    animation-name: example2;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example2; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -moz-animation-name: example2;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
}

@-moz-keyframes example2{
        0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 60deg);}
   50%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 210deg);letter-spacing: -1px;}
    100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes example2 {
   0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 60deg);}
   50%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 210deg);letter-spacing: -1px;}
    100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);}
}

@keyframes example2 {
    0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 60deg);}
   50%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 210deg);letter-spacing: -1px;}
    100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="title-pos title-style">
                    <span class="letter-rotated">H</span><span class="letter-rotated">i</span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Spans are inline and inline elements can't be animated. Try to change the display of `letter-rotated` to `inline-block`

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `display: inline-block;` to class `.letter-rotated` because only block elements can be animated.

Also I changed `example2` to use regular `transform` instead of a prefixed one.

The result:

```css
.title-pos{
   top: 40%;
   left: 50%;
   position: fixed;
   max-width: 500px;
   top:0
}

.title-style{
   font-size:35px;
   font-family: 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif;
}

.letter-rotated{
   font-size:70px;
   font-weight:600;
   transition: 1.5s;
}

.letter-rotated{
    display: inline-block;
    animation-name: example2;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example2; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -moz-animation-name: example2;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
}

@-moz-keyframes example2{
    0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 60deg);}
   50%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 210deg);letter-spacing: -1px;}
  100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes example2 {
    0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 60deg);}
   50%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 210deg);letter-spacing: -1px;}
  100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);}
}

@keyframes example2 {
    0%   {transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 60deg);}
   50%   {transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 210deg);letter-spacing: -1px;}
  100%   {transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="title-pos title-style">
  <span class="letter-rotated">H</span><span class="letter-rotated">i</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's it :)